# How to choose a color randomly from the list?

Tags: unity-game-engine, background-color

Unity C#
I made a list. The color changes after 5 seconds. I defined the color from which the list begins ("_currentIndex = 0"). The first color should always be the one I defined at the beginning. What I have means that each color on the list is selected one by one. After the last color everything comes back to the beginning.

I would like the first color to always be the same, but each subsequent one was chosen randomly from the list. It must be an infinite loop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ColorCycler : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Color[] Colors;
 public float Speed = 5;
 int _currentIndex;
 Camera _cam;
 bool _shouldChange = false;

 private int randomColors;

 void Start()
 {
     _cam = GetComponent<Camera>();

     _currentIndex = 0;
     SetColor(Colors[_currentIndex]);
 }


 public void SetColor(Color color)
 {
     _cam.backgroundColor = color;
 }

 public void Cycle()
 {
     _shouldChange = true;
 }

 void Update()
 {
     if (_shouldChange)
     {
         var startColor = _cam.backgroundColor;

         //start from color with number
         var endColor = Colors[0];
         if (_currentIndex + 1 < Colors.Length)
         {
             endColor = Colors[_currentIndex + 1];
         }

         var newColor = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, Time.deltaTime * Speed);
         SetColor(newColor);

         if (newColor == endColor)
         {
             _shouldChange = false;
             if (_currentIndex + 1 < Colors.Length)
             {
                 _currentIndex++;
             }
             else
             {
                 _currentIndex = 0;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a random element from a list then just choose a random index.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomIndex = random.Next(Colors.Count);
color = Colors[randomIndex];
```